# Smallest topology making projections continuous

Tags: general-topology

I'm stuck with a part of a question.

> Consider the unit circle $S1$ and the functions $a$, $b$ from $S1$ to $R$: $a(x,y)=x$ and $b(x,y)=y$.
>
> 2. Show that the smallest topology on $S1$ which makes both $a$ and $b$ continuous is  the Euclidian one.

There was a part 1 in which I proved that if I take the smallest one which makes one of them continuous, the topology is not Hausdorff.
For part 2 I've already shown that the Euclidian topology makes both $a$ and $b$ continuous. I think I now need to prove that the Euclidian topology is contained in any topology that makes $a$ and $b$ continuous by fixing this random topology and showing every Euclidian open is an open in this random topology. But I really do not know how.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Show that any topology that makes projections continuous must contain a basis of Euclidean topology, so it may not be any smaller than Euclidean topology.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the approach, but how do I show that? I think it reduces my problem to solving it for a basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euclidean topology $\mathcal{T}_e$ (the planar topology restricted to $S^1$) is a specific topology that makes both projections continuous. So if we by $\mathcal{T}$ denote the smallest topology that makes both of them continuous, we by definition have $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_e$.

If $(c,d)$ and $(e,f)$ are open intervals in the reals, then $a^{-1}[(c,d)] \cap b^{-1}[(e,f)]$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$ (as the intersection of two open sets, and these sets are open because of the continuity of $a$ and $b$). This set equals $((c,d) \times (e,f)) \cap S^1$. But sets of this form are the base for $\mathcal{T}_e$, so all basic elements of $\mathcal{T}_e$ are in $\mathcal{T}$ and so $\mathcal{T}_e \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ as well (as a topology is closed under unions). So we have $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T}_e$ as required.